# How to build a 20x20 board for a game on Python?

Tags: python

I'm a beginner and trying to create a board game that is similar to Checkers. I need to build a 20x20 board with rows named 1-20 and columns named A-T. I've built the board below but it seems very counter-intuitive and they are not initialized with numbers and letters. I want to take parameters such as "A5" for defining player move functions.

```
class Game:
def __init__(self):
    self._board = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "],
                   [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]
```

Comment: You might like to see a few ways to more efficiently create your 2D list: https://snakify.org/en/lessons/two_dimensional_lists_arrays/

Comment: You don't need to initialize them with numbers and letters because you will identify each cell by it's indices. e.g. `board[4][5]` identifies the 5th row, 6th column (remembering that python lists are 0-indexed). If you need to you can write a function to convert alphanumeric coordinates (e.g. `B4`) to index notation.

Comment: There are all sorts of ways to do this. One way is use a dictionary with keys like `'A4'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a two-dimensional list that has normal numeric indices (from 0-19) and then write functions that translate strings like "A5" into those indices.  If you put this logic in a class that implements magic methods like `__getitem__` and `__setitem__`, you can use these identifiers as subscripts (like `board["A5"]`) instead of having to call the functions by name.

For example:

```
from typing import List, Optional, Tuple


class Board:
    def __init__(self, size: int = 20):
        self._board: List[List[Optional[str]]] = [
            [None for _ in range(size)] for _ in range(size)
        ]

    def _get_coords(self, space: str) -> Tuple[int, int]:
        assert (
            space[1:].isdecimal()
            and space[0].isalpha()
            and space[0].isupper()
        ), "Specify spaces as uppercase letter and number, eg 'A5'"
        coords = int(space[1:]) - 1, ord(space[0]) - ord("A")
        assert all(
            i in range(len(self._board)) for i in coords
        ), f"{space} is outside of the board"
        return coords

    def __getitem__(self, space: str) -> Optional[str]:
        x, y = self._get_coords(space)
        return self._board[x][y]

    def __setitem__(self, space: str, piece: str) -> None:
        x, y = self._get_coords(space)
        self._board[x][y] = piece

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return (
            "\n".join(str(i+1).ljust(3) + " ".join(
                c if c else " " for c in row
            ) for i, row in enumerate(self._board))
            + "\n   " + " ".join(
                chr(ord("A") + c) for c in range(len(self._board))
            )
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    board = Board()
    board["A5"] = "O"
    board["B20"] = "X"
    print(board)
```

The benefit of keeping the internals in a normal list (even if you're not used to thinking in terms of zero-indexed lists yet) is that it will make it much easier to write logic that iterates over the board (like the `__str__` function does -- it would be a bit harder to write this function if the board were stored as nested dictionaries with named columns).